# Lightning Datatable scroll into view

Tags: lightning-datatable, scrolling

I need a way to programmatically scroll to a specified row in a Lightning Datatable. In my case I want to scroll-into-view based on search results that return a row number or key.

Can someone point me to a solution?

Thanks,
elJefe

Answer (score 0):

I found an embarrassingly simple workaround to the scroll into view problem. Instead of implementing a custom search function for my DataTable I rely on the browser search capability (Command+F). As you step through the list of found items, the DataTable scrolls them into view.